# What is the product after treating ethene successively with chlorine and water, sulfuric acid, and potassium hydroxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

**Question:**

> Ethene reacts with $\ce{Cl2}$ in $\ce{H2O}$ to form A. A on reaction with $\ce{H2SO4}$ followed by heating gives B. B on reaction with alcoholic $\ce{KOH}$ gives C. Find C.

**My answer is:**

A: $\ce{CH2(OH)CH2Cl}$
B: $\ce{CH2=CHCl}$
C: ethyne.

**Explanation:**

Ethene on reaction with chlorine water undergoes addition reaction to give A. A on reaction with $\ce{H2SO4}$ followed by heating undergoes dehydration to give B. B on reaction with alcoholic $\ce{KOH}$, undergoes elimination to give ethyne.

But the answer given is $\ce{CH2=CH-O-CH=CH2}$.

Where I am going wrong and what are the products?

Comment: I think diethyl ether is thermodynamically favourable because ethylene is not that stable. (less substituted alkene). Try this: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjRqbe04JTKAhXQGo4KHVHsAIAQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.anl.gov%2FPCS%2Facsfuel%2Fpreprint%2520archive%2FFiles%2F49_2_Philadelphia_10-04_1181.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFfQBSE_MRg0g1UG-Y9YR7MjSjI8Q&sig2=egb0mopsHHPvA0GNTXkKqg&bvm=bv.110151844,d.c2E

Comment: I don't know about this question, feels way too prone to "my school syllabus teaches that this reaction occurs with conc. H2SO4/ethanolic KOH, so only this reaction happens".

Comment: @Aditya Dev thank you very much for replying but can you please show the mechanism  of how it happens?(just tell me what happens step by step).

Comment: @orthocresol thank you very much for replying,do you mean to say only ethyne is formed?

Comment: It's the B product that's confusing. To get the required product, eliminate water from two molecules of A. Then alcoholic KOH will give the product that's given in your book. But, the more important part is "why intermolecular reaction takes place".

Comment: @ Aditya Dev ,thank you very much for replying,actually this is MCQ and ethyne is not present in option so to derive the answer we can carry out intermolecular reaction.

Comment: @Aditya Dev can you please elaborate on the mechanism?

Comment: http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/11/14/ether-synthesis-via-alcohols-and-acid/

Comment: yes,now i understand it,by adjusting the temparature we can enable ether formation instead of dehydration,but temperature is not given ,anyhow ethyne is not there in the option so we can assume that ether is formed in second step which undergoes elimination to produce CH2=CH−O−CH=CH2CH2=CH−O−CH=CH2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first reaction is a [hydrochlorination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrohalogenation) reaction:

[image: step 1]

The second reaction is an [acid catalyzed ether synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ether#Dehydration_of_alcohols). The the solution is full of other 2-chloroethanol, which is capable of acting as a nucleophile in an $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction to eject $\ce{H2O}$. This is reaction will have a much lower energy barrier than the dehydration you proposed, which requires the extraction of an aliphatic hydrogen. The ether synthesis mechanism can be seen here:

[image: step 2]

The final step is a series of two [$\mathrm{E2}$ reactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimination_reaction#E2_mechanism) (shown condensed here):

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]